# A question from functions chapter

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Consider the function $g(x)$ defined as $$g(x)\left[x^{2^{2010}-1} - 1\right]=(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)\cdots(x^{2^{2009}} +1)-1$$ then (one or more than one correct)

A) $g(2)=2$ 
  B) $g(2)=1$ 
 C) $g(\frac{1}{2})=-1$ 
 D) $g(\frac{1}{2})=0$

I dont even understand how to go about this problem. Please Help.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat I dont know if the answers to the question over here in my sheet are coorect or not but it tells the answers are A,B,D.

Comment: It obviously cannot be both A and B!

Comment: How can A and B be both correct??????

Comment: that is what im confused about ._.

Comment: I dont know thats why i put up the question over here. Please help me. A detailed solution would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You can eliminate $g(2) = 1$ by looking at the equation $\pmod 2$. You can also eliminate $g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = 0$ because the RHS is larger than $0$ (it is a product of terms larger than $1$, from which we subtract $1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show that $$(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)\ldots(x^{2^{2009}}+1) = \frac{x^{2^{2010}}-1}{x-1}$$
by multiplying both sides by $x-1$. The products on the LHS will "telescope" in a sense, by getting $(x-1)(x+1) = x^2-1$, then $(x^2-1)(x^2+1) = x^4 - 1$, and so on (one can use induction to be rigorous).

Hence $$g(x)\left(x^{2^{2010}-1}-1\right)=\frac{x^{2^{2010}}-1}{x-1}-1 = \frac{x^{2^{2010}}-x}{x-1} = x\frac{x^{2^{2010}-1}-1}{x-1}$$

Therefore $g(x) = \frac{x}{x-1}$.

Plugging $x = 2$ and $x = \frac{1}{2}$ gives us $g(2) = 2$ and $g\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = -1$.

---

EDIT:

Ok so in the beginning I claim that $(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)\ldots\left(x^{2^n}+1\right) = \frac{x^{2^{n+1}}-1}{x-1}$ for all $n \geq 0$.

To write this in product notation, I mean $$\prod\limits_{i=0}^n\left(x^{2^i}+1\right) = \frac{x^{2^{n+1}}-1}{x-1}$$ I will show this by induction on $n$.

First when $n = 0$ we obtain $x+1 = \frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ which is true.
Now assume the equation holds for $k$. Thus $$\prod\limits_{i=0}^k\left(x^{2^i}+1\right) = \frac{x^{2^{k+1}}-1}{x-1}$$

Then $$\prod\limits_{i=0}^{k+1}\left(x^{2^i}+1\right) = \frac{x^{2^{k+1}}-1}{x-1}\left(x^{2^{k+1}}+1\right) = \frac{\left(x^{2^{k+1}}\right)^2-1^2}{x-1} = \frac{x^{2^{k+2}}-1}{x-1}$$

hence the formula holds for $k + 1$.

I believe this is a standard trick, and I have seen it in some contest math problems, although I cannot recall a specific one. I think there was a Putnam problem involving this identity. This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067075/common-proof-for-1x1x21x4-1x2n-dfrac1-x2n11-x) also refers to that identity.

Comment: $x^{2^{2009}. x=x^2^{2009}+1$ notx^{2^{2010}}$

Comment: Pardon, what part of the answer are you referring to?

Comment: the first relation you mentioned

Comment: There is some problem with the Latex in your first comment. Are you saying that $x^{2^{2009}}x = x^{2^{2009}+1}$, not $x^{2^{2010}}$? You would be correct, but I did not use this in that relation.

Comment: I think the correct form of question is:

${g(x)[(x^2)^{2010} -1]=(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1) . . .(x^2)^{2009}}-1$

Comment: @TobErnack The whole answer seems very clear excapt the first. Can you please elaborate how you got that first step? Perhaps you can "show how we can show that $(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)…(x^{2^{2009}}+1)=(x^{2^{2010}}−1)/(x−1)$

Comment: I edited the body of my answer to address this.

Comment: is there some particular name of this standard trick?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know. I am trying to find a reference or problem that involves this.

Comment: Ah there we go, I used the search bar on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067075/common-proof-for-1x1x21x4-1x2n-dfrac1-x2n11-x