# Find the limit in probability of the sequence $(Z_{n})_{n \in N}$

Tags: probability

the truth is, the probability subject is very difficult for me, I have this other exercise with which. I don't know where to start, could you help me? I would appreciate it very much.

Let $(X_{n})_{n \in}$ be a family of independent random variables with Bernoulli distribution of parameter $\frac{1}{2}$. For each $n \in N$ we define the random variable:
$$Z_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{X_{k}}{2^k}$$
Find the limit in probability of the sequence $(Z_{n})_{n \in N}$

Comment: I would bet money that $(Z_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in probability to a $\mathcal{U}[0,1]$ random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M_{Z_n}(t)$ be the moment generating function of $Z_n$. Then using independence $$M_{Z_n}(t)=\mathbb{E}\big(e^{tZ_n}\big)=\prod_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}\Big(e^{tX_k/2^k}\Big)=\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{k=1}^n\Big(1+e^{t/2^k}\Big)$$ You can see [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tawib2rzxk) that $M_{Z_n}(t) \longrightarrow \frac{e^t-1}{t}$. The limit corresponds to the moment generating function for a $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ random variable.

Comment: Makes sense to me, thank you very much!

Comment: The "you can see here that" graphical argumentation doesn't constiture a proof. You should say that you apply an identity for example given and established in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2067075)